# Fully Cooked can Hornet ham!

Tags: food-safety

I bought a fully cooked can Hormel Ham. It is to be refrigerated however I left it in my trunk for 4 hours. It is now in my fridge. Should it be okay???

Comment: We can’t tell you whether it’s *spoiled* - but based on our [generic post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat), we can conclude that your ham is no longer *safe* by food safety standards. Note that there’s a difference between the two - the latter not necessarily meaning the former. That said, welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: This would only be a duplicate question if it was about 'food'.  But canned ham is very specific, and doesn't fall under that general case

Comment: @Terri Garrett Canned ham may or not be marked as 'keep refrigerated'.  If so, it's bad and you should throw it out before poisoning yourself.  But if it's not, it has a shelf life of a couple years in theory.  I would eat it more promptly to compensate for the stay in the (presumably hot) trunk, but it should still be fine.